# For Loop in R replacing Object Values at each iteration

Tags: r, loops

I am struggling to figure out how to create a for loop in which some initial objects (`u`, `l`, `h`, and `y`) and their values are updated and reported at the end of each iteration of the loop. And that the loop takes into account the values of the prior iteration as the basis (for example after updating the above objects, the `runif` function takes the updated values of `u` and `l` in drawing a `q`. I keep getting the same result repeated with no variation, and I am unsure as to what might be the best way to resolve this.

Apologies in advance as I am fairly new to R and coding in general.

```
reset = {
l = 0.1 #lower bound of belief in theta  
u = 0.9 #upper bound of belief in theta
h = 0.2 #lower legal threshold, below which an action is not liable
y = 0.8 #upper legal threshold, above which an action is liable 
}
### need 1-u <= h <= y <= 1-l  for each t along every path of play

period = c(1:100)   ## Number of periods in the iteration of the loop.

for (t in 1:length(period)) {
q = runif(1,min = l, max = u)  ### 1 draw of q from a uniform distribution
q 
  probg = function(q,l,u){(u - (1-q))/(u-l)} ### probability of being found guilty given q in the ambiguous region
  probg(q,l,u)

  probi = function(q,l,u){1-probg(q,l,u)} ### probability of being found innocent given q in the ambiguous region
  probi(q,l,u)

    ruling = if(q>=y | probg(q,l,u) > 1){print("Guilty")              ###Strict liability

  } else if(q<=h | probi(q,l,u) > 1) {print("Innocent")               ###Permissible

  } else if(q>h & q<y) {                                              ###Ambiguous region


  discovery = sample(c('guilty','not guilty'), size=1, replace=TRUE, prob=c(probg(q,l,u),probi(q,l,u)))  ### court discovering whether a particular ambiguous q is permissible or not

  } 
  discovery
  ruling

if(ruling == "not guilty") {u = 1-q} else if (ruling == "guilty") {l = 1-q} else (print("beliefs unchanged"))      
if(ruling == "not guilty"){h = 1 - u} else if (ruling == "guilty") {y = 1 - l}  else (print("legal threshold unchanged"))              #### legal adjustment and updating of beliefs in ambiguous region after discovery of liability


probg(q,l,u)
probi(q,l,u)
modelparam = c(l,u,h,y)
show(modelparam)

}
```

Comment: What would be your expected result?

Comment: Looks like the problem is how you deal with `ruling`, currently it never takes "guilty" or "not guilty", so your script won't work the way you hope it would.

Comment: If you replace "Guilty" by "guilty" and "Innocent" by "not guilty" it should work.

Comment: My expected result is having the bounds `l` `u` `h` `y` update at each iteration and converge and that the `q` that is drawn at each iteration takes on a value between the updated bounds.

Comment: Thank you @KevinCazelles, that seemed to do the trick!